# Jquery DataTables Search box returns no results if data was added using fnAddData?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use ajax call to get array of data from server then add it to my datatable using fnAddData and it displays the data just fine, the problem is that when i type anything on the searchbox, the table displays no matching rows.. I guess it has something to do with the fnAddData?

here's my code:

```
$oTbl = $('#tbl').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});

$.ajax({
    url: "Fn.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {fn: "readData"},
    cache: false,
    success: function (res) {
        $oTbl.fnClearTable();
        $oTbl.fnAddData(JSON.parse(res));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Json Example:  {readData:[{"id":1,"name":"clearing House"}]       



dTable = $('#tbl').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",       
    "bProcessing": true,       
    "sAjaxSource": "Fn.php",  //your url      
    "sAjaxDataProp": "readData", //your json obj
        "aoColumns": [
                      { "mDataProp": "id", "bVisible":false },
                      { "sTitle":"Provider Name", "mDataProp": "name" }
                     ]                       
    });


 Hope this helps u...
```

Comment: how will i return the json object?? im using php on server side so do i have to echo readData?

Comment: Refer these link http://datatables.net/examples/     http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html